# Correct Place to enable windows services in GPO?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows-service

Which is the correct place to enable windows services through GPO on Windows Server 2008? The domain has computers running XP, Vista, and 7.

Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > System Services

or

Computer Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Services

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > System Services settings are enforced, meaning a user cannot change the setting.

Computer Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Services are not enforced, meaning a user can change the setting.

From Microsoft:

> The key difference between preferences and policy settings is
>   enforcement.